# EntityFramework.Plus: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

I am using the audit feature of EntityFramework.Plus in an EF6 Code First project. When I add the following code:

```
public virtual DbSet<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<AuditEntryProperty> AuditEntryProperties { get; set; }

static EntityContext()
   {
            AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.AutoSavePreAction = (context, audit) =>
            {
                var Entities = context as EntityContext;
                if (Entities != null)
                {
                    Entities.AuditEntries.AddRange(audit.Entries);
                }
                else throw new InvalidOperationException($"Context is null for {context.Database.Connection}");
            };
        }
```

I get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:\r\n\r\nWebsite.Core.Entities.Audit: : EntityType 'Audit'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nAudits:
>   EntityType: EntitySet 'Audits' is based on type 'Audit' that has no
>   keys defined.\r\n",   "exceptionType":
>   "System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException"

Audit is not an entity in my project - as stated by the error. This error is removed when I remove the code above.

Can anyone help? Is it possible to suppress model validation for external library types?

Thanks in advance

HS

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Looking at the error:

> EntityType 'Audit' has no key defined

It seems you also mapped the Audit entity which should not be mapped.

Look at your EntityContext if you have a line similar to this and remove it:

```
public virtual DbSet<Audit> Audits { get; set; }
```

**Answer Sub-Questions**

We have the Audit class in our library but to have it appear in the context, it should be mapped (which we don't want). It's pretty hard to debug this issue since you are the only one to get it.

Can you try the following code in a new project and the current one? In both cases, it should work without problems.

If you can, try to provide more information to let us reproduce this issue.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Z.EntityFramework.Plus.Lab
{
    public partial class Form_Issue_Audit_HeySatan : Form
    {
        public Form_Issue_Audit_HeySatan()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (var ctx = new EntityContext())
            {
                var audit = new Audit();

                ctx.EntitySimples.Add(new EntitySimple {ColumnInt = 1});

                ctx.SaveChanges(audit);
            }
        }

        public class EntityContext : DbContext
        {
            static EntityContext()
            {
                AuditManager.DefaultConfiguration.AutoSavePreAction = (context, audit) =>
                {
                    var Entities = context as EntityContext;
                    if (Entities != null)
                    {
                        Entities.AuditEntries.AddRange(audit.Entries);
                    }
                    else throw new InvalidOperationException($"Context is null for {context.Database.Connection}");
                };
            }

            public EntityContext() : base("CodeFirstEntities")
            {
            }

            public DbSet<EntitySimple> EntitySimples { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<AuditEntryProperty> AuditEntryProperties { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Types().Configure(x => x.ToTable(GetType().DeclaringType != null ? GetType().DeclaringType.FullName.Replace(".", "_") + "_" + x.ClrType.Name : ""));

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
        }

        public class EntitySimple
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int? ColumnInt { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Johnathan, thanks for your fast reply. You're not going to believe this but there are no other DbSet<Audit> in the project!  In fact, Audit doesn't even exist. That was my old audit entity that your code has now replaced. Could there be anywhere where this is cached - an entity framework metadata cache maybe? Also, this only happens when i introduce the code above.If I remove the new auditing code, I get this error.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I am sorry about my late response. I have managed to get it working, I achieved this by rebuilding the entire WebApi project from scratch, and copying the code and configuration over. There must have been some strange caching issue that was caching the old model. Thanks for your help and diligence.

Comment: Hi @JonathanMagnan, what is best way I can retrieve records at a specific time. I only saw code that retrieve data after calling `SaveChanges()` but I want to retrieve the history while reading data?

Comment: Could you elaborate on `but I want to retrieve the history while reading data?`. I just want to make sure I answer to the right question

Comment: @KnowHoper What exactly did you do? I am facing the same problem. but in my case, I've created another Entity with the same name in the past together with a second DBContext. Now my project is stuck. Actually was an Entity that manages a many to many relationship. I am going crazy.